# Inline conditional JSX - Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <div>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Is it possible to have inline conditional jsx without the closing tag? I need to insert `<div className="board-row">` every 3rd square.

```jsx
const gridSquares = squares.map((reference, square) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {square % 3 == 0 && square % 3 !== squares.length && (
        <div className="board-row">
      )}
      <Square
        key={square}
        value={squares[square]}
        onSquareClick={() => handleClick(square)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});

return (
  <div>
    <div className="status">{status}</div>
    {gridSquares}
  </div>
);
```

**Error:**

```
./src/App.js
Syntax error: C:/Code/Tutorial/src/App.js: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <div> (57:4)

  55 |       <Square key={square} value={squares[square]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(square)} />
  56 | 
> 57 |     </React.Fragment>
     |     ^
  58 |     
  59 |   });
```

Comment: Nope, JSX must be structurally valid. Have you considered using a CSS grid layout?

Comment: `<div className="board-row"></div>` is valid

Answer (score 1):

JSX isn't like an HTML template. Each element is compiled to JS and must be structurally valid.

Assuming you're trying to make some sort of grid with 3 elements per row, you could use a [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for simplicity without worrying about markup

```jsx
return (
  <div>
    <div className="status">{status}</div>
    <div className="board-grid">
      {squares.map((square, index) => (
        <Square
          key={index}
          value={square}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(square)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

```css
.board-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 squares per row */
}
```

[image: Edit elegant-shtern-nqjimt]